# Why checkboxes don't work correctly?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm using [this library](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/checkbox) and want to perform a list of items, and every of them has it's own checkbox. I made generation of these items, and onClick method works ( shows information about  clicked checkbox, but it doesn't "draws" that checkbox is checked.Where is the mistake? Here i my code:

```
mport React, { Component }            from 'react'
import { Divider,Label,List,Checkbox,Header } from 'semantic-ui-react'

    export default class Menu extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {

            }
        }

        render() {
            let { tags } = this.props;

            return (
                <div className="ui segment basic" >
                    {typeof tags === "undefined" ?
                        <div>Select partner and process</div>
                    :
                        this.getTagListItems(tags)
                    }
                </div>
            )
        }

        getTagListItems = tagsData => {
            let tags = [];
            for(let i=0; i<tagsData.length; i++){
                if ( tagsData[i].children.length !==0 ) {
                    tags.push(
                        <div key = { i }>
                            <Header as="h3">{ tagsData[i].name }</Header>
                            <Divider/>
                            <List>
                                {this.getTagCheckboxes(tagsData[i].children)}
                            </List>
                        </div>
                    );
                }
            }
            return tags;
        };

        getTagCheckboxes = checkboxData => {
            let checkboxes = [];
            for(let i=0; i<checkboxData.length; i++) {
                checkboxes.push(
                    <List.Item key = { checkboxData[i].id }>
                        <Checkbox label   = { checkboxData[i].name }
                                  id      = { checkboxData[i].id }
                                  onClick = { this.setTag }
                        />
                        <List.Content floated="right" >
                            <Label>
                                0
                            </Label>
                        </List.Content>
                    </List.Item>
                );
            }
            return checkboxes;
        };

        setTag = (e, data) => {
            console.log('Check', data)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `checked` property for the checkbox that you need to check.

First you need to initialize your state where you will keep the selected value.

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: {},
        }
}
```

then you need to compare if the checkbox you are rendering is selected in the state.

```
<Checkbox label   = { checkboxData[i].name }
          id      = { checkboxData[i].id }
          onClick = { this.setTag }
          checked = { this.state.data.id === checkboxData[i].id }
/>
```

Finally inside the `setTag` callback, you need to set the selected value when the user clicks the checkbox

```
setTag = (e, data) => {
        console.log('Check', data)
        this.setState({ data });
}
```

This will work as a radio button, because the state can only keep one item at a type, if you want to allow the user to check multiple checkboxes at the same time, you will need to add a `checked` property to each item, and toggle it when calling `onClick`

Comment: yes I need to allow user to check multiple checkboxes. if I add  checked = { this.state.data.id === checkboxData[i].id }  to every checkbox in every item, then it's still possible to check just 1 checkbox :(